# Azure Blob Storage .uploadStream() hangs on larger files

Tags: node.js, express, azure-blob-storage, busboy

I'm currently working on the capability to upload larger files to Azure Blob Storage using Express.js and the `@azure/storage-blob` package.

What I have works fine on files <5mb but anything larger will "fail" at some point on the upload stream. I say "fail" because no error (that I can see) is thrown, it just hangs up mid-upload. Because there is no error I am struggling to figure out what could be causing the error.

index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const volleyball = require('volleyball');
const cors = require('cors');
const busboy = require('connect-busboy')

require('dotenv').config()
const fileRoutes = require('./routes/files.routes')

const app = express();

// Enable Logging
app.use(volleyball);

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// run cors middleware
app.use(cors());

//process body contents for file uploads
app.use(busboy({
    highWaterMark: (1 * 1024 * 1024), 
    fileHwm: (1 * 1024 * 1024) / 2,
}))

app.use('/files', fileRoutes);

// Setting the port and publishing to that port
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port', port);
});
```

Code for the `/files/t2` route:

```js
const storageblob = require('@azure/storage-blob')
const {v4: uuidv4} = require('uuid')

const busboy = require('connect-busboy')

const rand = require('randomstring') // todo: remove from final

let sharedClient = null

const createClient = async () => {
    const connectionString = process.env.STORAGE_CS
    const containerName = '3ac53750-882a-11ec-8579-db09c3889ffa'

    // Create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
    const blobServiceClient = await storageblob.BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);

    sharedClient = containerClient
}

const saveFile = async (req, res) => {
    if (sharedClient) {
        console.log('already set')
    } else {
        console.log('attempting to set')
        await createClient()
    }

    if (req.busboy) {
        req.busboy.on('file', async (fieldname, file, filename) => {
            console.log('Starting....')
            const blobClient = sharedClient.getBlockBlobClient(filename.filename)

            const bufferSize = (1 * 1024 * 1024) / 2

            const response = await blobClient.uploadStream(
                file,
                bufferSize,
                5,
                {
                    onProgress: (ev) => {
                        console.log(ev)
                        // console.log({file})
                    },
                    blobHTTPHeaders: {blobContentType: filename.mimeType}
                })
            response._response.status
            console.log({response})
            try {
            } catch (e) {
                console.log({e})
            }

            file.on('data', () => {
                console.log('we have an data call')
            })

            file.on('error', () => {
                console.log('we have an error - inside')
            })

            file.on('limit', () => {
                console.log('we have a limit reached - inside')
            })

            console.log('ending...')
        })

        req.busboy.on('error', () => {
            console.log('we have an error')
        })

        req.busboy.on('finish', () => {
            console.log('we finished')
        })

        req.busboy.on('close', () => {
            console.log('we closed')
        })

        req.on('aborted', () => {
            console.log('aborted')
        })

        console.log('starting pipe')
        req.pipe(req.busboy)

        res.send('finished...')
    }
}

module.exports = {
    saveFile,
}
```

Here is an excerpt of what the logs look like when attempting to upload an 11MB file:

```
MVPJ <â€”â€” 200 OK 6 B text/html; charset=utf-8 (<â€”> 2.8 ms)
{ loadedBytes: 524288 }
IeGN â€”â€”> POST /files/t2 11.49 MB multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------824775949779732965782851
already set
starting pipe
Starting....
IeGN <â€”â€” 200 OK 6 B text/html; charset=utf-8 (<â€”> 3.9 ms)
{ loadedBytes: 524288 }
{ loadedBytes: 1048576 }
E7Uh â€”â€”> POST /files/t2 11.49 MB multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------307975744074310648853410
already set
starting pipe
Starting....
E7Uh <â€”â€” 200 OK 6 B text/html; charset=utf-8 (<â€”> 3.1 ms)
{ loadedBytes: 524288 }
gIIV â€”â€”> POST /files/t2 11.49 MB multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------174965235814957167411128
already set
starting pipe
Starting....
gIIV <â€”â€” 200 OK 6 B text/html; charset=utf-8 (<â€”> 3.2 ms)
{ loadedBytes: 524288 }
{ loadedBytes: 1048576 }
OGOc â€”â€”> POST /files/t2 11.49 MB multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------880875904437719845837223
already set
starting pipe
Starting....
OGOc <â€”â€” 200 OK 6 B text/html; charset=utf-8 (<â€”> 3.1 ms)
{ loadedBytes: 524288 }
loMo â€”â€”> POST /files/t2 11.49 MB multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------121962168533176166251418
attempting to set
starting pipe
Starting....
loMo <â€”â€” 200 OK 6 B text/html; charset=utf-8 (<â€”> 31.2 ms)
{ loadedBytes: 524288 }
{ loadedBytes: 1048576 }
{ loadedBytes: 1572864 }
{ loadedBytes: 2097152 }
{ loadedBytes: 2621440 }
{ loadedBytes: 3145728 }
```

During this round of testing, it was failing pretty fast right around 500KB to 1MB. Other attempts have gotten as high as 6MB before failing. This leads me to believe it's not some hard limit but a throughput issue possibly? There doesn't seem to be much of a correlation between frequency and restarting the container/express server and where it fails.

**Update 1**

I've started to average higher upload amounts before hanging by increasing the maxConcurrency to 400 which seems to be ridiculously high from the examples I've seen which make between 5 and 20 seem like the norm. Not sure what this shows but it is interesting.

```
5s5m â€”â€”> POST /files/t2 25.6 MB multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------075957127342913853541742
attempting to set
starting pipe
Starting....
5s5m <â€”â€” 200 OK 6 B text/html; charset=utf-8 (<â€”> 36.0 ms)
{ loadedBytes: 524288 }
{ loadedBytes: 1048576 }
{ loadedBytes: 1572864 }
{ loadedBytes: 2097152 }
{ loadedBytes: 2621440 }
{ loadedBytes: 3145728 }
{ loadedBytes: 3670016 }
{ loadedBytes: 4194304 }
{ loadedBytes: 4718592 }
{ loadedBytes: 5242880 }
{ loadedBytes: 5767168 }
{ loadedBytes: 6291456 }
{ loadedBytes: 6815744 }
{ loadedBytes: 7340032 }
{ loadedBytes: 7864320 }
{ loadedBytes: 8388608 }
{ loadedBytes: 8912896 }
{ loadedBytes: 9437184 }
{ loadedBytes: 9961472 }
{ loadedBytes: 10485760 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem theory**

I ran into a similar issue and this is how I understand it. (Don't pin me on this though as I am no expert)

1. When you call `req.pipe(req.busboy)` the data from the req stream is piped into busboy, and in turn into the file stream(s), and starts flowing (this is important)
2. So the data is flowing in and the listener `req.busboy.on('file', async (fieldname, file, filename) => { .. }` is triggered, in which you call `const response = await blobClient.uploadStream(...)`
3. My theory on where it goes wrong is: Busboy processes the last bytes of the stream, but `blobClient` hasn't completed uploading everything yet. However the busboy stream ends and closes. At that point the blobClient thinks the stream upload has completed and stops processing (hence stopping "in the middle"). So basically 2 processes are reading the same stream but at different speeds, and one of them decides when finished.
4. Since you register your `file.on('data', ..);` listeners after `await blobClient.uploadStream(...)` which only completes after the busboy stream is already closed, you are too late to register the listeners and see the log messages.

**Solution**

Again, apologies for any inaccuracies as this is how I understand it. Feel free to improve my answer!

We need to pipe the `file` stream into a separate Readable stream that only `blobClient` reads from. For this we use a [PassThrough](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#class-streampassthrough)

```
req.busboy.on('file', async (fieldname, file, filename) => {

    const pt = new PassThrough(); // import {PassThrough} from "stream";

    const blobClient = sharedClient.getBlockBlobClient(filename.filename)

    const bufferSize = (1 * 1024 * 1024) / 2

    const uploadPromise = blobClient.uploadStream(file, bufferSize, 5,{
        onProgress: (ev) => {
            console.log(ev);
        }
    })

    file.on('error', () => {
        console.log('we have an error - inside')
    })

    file.pipe(pt);

    const response = await uploadPromise;

    //....
});
```

1. Create the passthrough which basically just passes the input bytes to the output stream.
2. Call `uploadStream` asynchronously. Nothing happens yet as we haven't piped the `file` stream yet.
3. pipe the `file` stream into the passthrough stream that is used for the upload
4. await the promise in case you want to do anything afterwards.